# Objective-C - HTTP load failed (error code: -1004 [1:61]) for Task in iOS11

Tags: http, ios11

I'm trying to perform a datatask with URLSession, when I run it on iOS11 device (iPhone 5S) I get a console error:

```
2017-09-22 15:22:17.942015-0300 app[1355:283536] TIC TCP Conn Failed [3:0x1c417af40]: 1:61 Err(61) 
2017-09-22 15:22:17.943698-0300 app[1355:283536] Task <A32F0275-75C3-4F64-AB92-2E37527AB813>.<0> HTTP load failed (error code: -1004 [1:61])
2017-09-22 15:22:17.945265-0300 app[1355:283676] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1004
```

Running on Simulator it doesn't happen.

What's causing it or how to fix it?

> Here's what I'm doing

```
#define kEcardURL @"https://example.com/mobile/services/ecard/"

- (void)doSomething {

    //Params Configuration
    NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [oauth.userData valueForKey:@"wsuserid"], @"token",
                          nil];

    NSString *path = @"fotoCartao";
    NSData* params = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:0 error:nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", kEcardURL, path]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:params];


    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [[self session] dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;

    if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil) {
      if ([httpResponse statusCode] == 200) {
        //do stuff
      }
    }
  }];
  [dataTask resume];
  }
}

- (NSURLSession *)session {
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
  // Session Configuration
  NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

  // Initialize Session
  _session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
  });
  return _session;
}
```

Comment: You need to show some code.

Comment: Edit your question to add it there, otherwise it's not very readable. Also add ALL the relevant code. For all I know the problem could be your URL, but we can't see that.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure the url is supported by running the following commands:

```
curl -v https://example.com/mobile/services/ecard/

nscurl --verbose --ats-diagnostics https://example.com/mobile/services/ecard/
```

Verify that you are not using cyphers hashes and protocols that are no longer supported by apple.

IOS 11 no longer supports these:

*Cyphers:*

- RC4
- 3DES-CBC
- AES-CBC

*Hashes:*

- MD5
- SHA-1

Key Sizes:

- <2048-bit RSA Pub Keys

*Protocols:*

- http://
- SSLv3
- TLS 1.0
- TLS 1.1

If they are not supported you can whitelist the domain by using
the NSAppTransportSecurity property in you application plist file.